# Rails DateTime format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timestamp, date-format, datecreated

I have two different applications in rails 5.

I can't understand why in one of them (newest one) when I create a record the value of `created_at is "2019-11-25 14: 08: 04.114384"`

While in old the value of `created_at is "25/11/2019 14:09:21.293691"`

The 2 values are created automatically after creating a record, for example using `modelName.save`

How can this happen? The two app are in the same version.

How can I make the older app create the CREATED_AT value correctly and consistently (Just like the new one: "2019-11-25 14: 08: 04.114384")?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Where are you seeing that? created_at value is a DateTime object, you are seeing the string representation, usually set up as a language localization, could it be that both apps has different languages set up? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Comment: If you want to always display a date in a given format with not "magic" behind the scenes, then use I18n module to localize the date with a specific format when you want to stringify it.